# Every Item in FlatList is same size, but need to be individual size defined by image

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new in React native and have a problem with mapping user feeds. I use FlatList component and when rendering every item has same size View, but images are different sizes. how to give to rendered View component height auto?

for more clearity: if highest image from feed is 1000px, all feed image's section are 1000px.

```
<FlatList
   data={filteredUsers}
   renderItem={({ item }) => <Feed {...item} navigation={navigation} />}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id}
 />
```

///

```
 <FastImage
       style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: imageSize?.height }}
       source={{
          uri: feed?.mobileWEBPurl,
          priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
       resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
       fallback={true}
       onLoad={() => console.log("Image loaded")}
       onError={() => console.log("Error loading image")}
  />
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add what the <Feed /> component looks like

Comment: Thanks for answer, feed looks like as a instagram feed. top section, image and bottom section. Images are different sizes, so feed container should be different, but all feed View are size of heighest feed

Answer (score 0):

try add getItemLayout

```
 getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
    length: data[index].height,
     offset: data.slice(0, index).reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr.height, 0),
     index,
 })}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but code doesn't work. All feed are size of feed with heighest image